# Class returns empty list

Tags: python, list, class

I am trying to write a function which cleans up URLs (strips them of anything like "www.", "http://" etc.) to create a list that I can sort alphabetically.

I have tried to do this by creating a class including a method to detect the term I would like to remove from the URL-string, and remove it. The bit where I am struggling is that I want to add the modified URLs to a new list called `new_strings`, and then use that new list when I call the method for a second time on a different term, so that step by step I can remove all unwanted elements from the URL-string.

For some reason my current code returns an empty list, and I am also struggling to understand whether `new_strings` should be passed to `__init__` or not? I guess I am a bit confused with global vs. local variables, and some help and explanation would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks! Code below.

```
class URL_Cleaner(object):
    def __init__(self, old_strings, new_strings, term):
        self.old_strings = old_strings
        self.new_strings = new_strings
        self.term = term

    new_strings = []

    def delete_term(self, new_strings):
        for self.string in self.old_strings:
            if self.term in string:
                new_string = string.replace(term, "")
                self.new_strings.append(new_string)
            else:
                self.new_strings.append(string)
        return self.new_strings

    print "\n" .join(new_strings) #for checking; will be removed later

strings = ["www.google.com", "http://www.google.com", "https://www.google.com"]
new_strings = []
www = URL_Cleaner(strings, new_strings, "www.")
```

Comment: Class `__init__()` methods don't return anything, they just initialize their first argument, a class instance usually named `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are we making a class to do this?

```
for string in strings:
     string.replace("www.","")
```

Isn't that what you're trying to accomplish?

Regardless the problem is in your class definition. Pay attention to scopes:

```
class URL_Cleaner(object):
    def __init__(self, old_strings, new_strings, term):
        """These are all instance objects"""
        self.old_strings = old_strings
        self.new_strings = new_strings
        self.term = term

    new_strings = [] # this is a class object

    def delete_term(self, new_strings):
        """You never actually call this function! It never does anything!"""
        for self.string in self.old_strings:
            if self.term in string:
                new_string = string.replace(term, "")
                self.new_strings.append(new_string)
            else:
                self.new_strings.append(string)
        return self.new_strings

    print "\n" .join(new_strings) #for checking; will be removed later
    # this is referring the class object, and will be evaluated when
    # the class is defined, NOT when the object is created!
```

I've commented your code the necessary reasons.... To fix:

```
class URL_Cleaner(object):
    def __init__(self, old_strings):
        """Cleans URL of 'http://www.'"""
        self.old_strings = old_strings
        cleaned_strings = self.clean_strings()
    def clean_strings(self):
        """Clean the strings"""
        accumulator = []
        for string in self.old_strings:
            string = string.replace("http://", "").replace("www.", "")
            # this might be better as string = re.sub("http://(?:www.)?", "", string)
            # but I'm not going to introduce re yet.
            accumulator.append(string)
        return accumulator
        # this whole function is just:
        ## return [re.sub("http://(?:www.)?", "", string, flags=re.I) for string in self.old_strings]
        # but that's not as readable imo.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your solution. One quick comment: the reason I am using a Class is because I want to clean the URLs from various different items, so I wanted to create different instances of the same class. And therefore I also think there is a need to pass `accumulator` to `clean_strings()` as an argument, so that the list created by the previous instance can be modified further?

Comment: After some further playing with it, your code throws an error in line 5: "global name 'clean_strings' is not defined" - any ideas?

Comment: @Matthias oops, should be self.clean_strings()

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define new_strings as

```
self.new_strings = []
```

and remove new_strings argument from the constructor.

The 'new_strings' and 'self.new_strings' are two different lists.